# How to deal with special characters like � in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

I am using pandas.read_csv() to read a csv file, but characters like the copyright symbol are getting converted to �

For example, in excel I will see this value - 
/ORGANIZATION/AFFLUENT-ATTACHÃ©-CLUB-2

In jupyter notebook in turns to this - 
/ORGANIZATION/AFFLUENT-ATTACH�-CLUB-2 in one dataframe 
/ORGANIZATION/AFFLUENT-ATTACHÉ-CLUB-2 in the other

I need to do an inner join of 2 dataframes, both of which have a column with these unique IDs, but values like these are getting left out.

I thought it might be something to do with the enconding, so I found that the encoding type is cp1252 for both csv files. I do not know if this information is useful.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8 or UTF-16 while reading.